# I am making a simple app with button in it and toast activity to be performed on clicking those buttons?

Tags: android

I am making a simple app with button in it. A toast should appear upon clicking the button.

I get the error

> error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Context

at the following lines of code

```
Button b1;
b1 = new Button(findViewById(R.id.button)) // Error on this line
```

Comment: If the button is in your XML just do `Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);`

Comment: In the future, copy the actual code here, so I don't have to flip back and forth between your screenshot and this post.

Comment: @AndrewBrooke you beat me to the punch in the comments. I'll delete my answer if you'd like to post yours as the solution.

Comment: @jheimbouch don't worry about it man!

Comment: Okay!! Thank you next time I will paste the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the View back to a button like this:

```
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```